# EditText loses focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have two EditText widgets inside the ScrollView widget. THe overall structure is:

- LinearLayout

  - ScrollView

    - RelativeLayout

      - EditText
      - EditText

I have `OnFocusChangeListener` on both EditText components, where i say that if this component has focus, then *remove* focus from another component and *request* focus for this component

The problem is that when in the first EditText i start writing text and then press return or touch another EditText, then focus comes back to the first EditText and continues there. This happens only once, and never again until the activity is refreshed.

P.S. THis happens only when focus changes from the first EditText to the second one, but it works normally if I go from the second to the first

What can be done to get rid of this small bug

I think I found what was the problem. I also had a onKeyboardOut listener, where i remove focus first before keyboard pops out and set it back afterwards, this lead to such a weird problem